# IFeatureCollection has been disposed error in ServiceStack

Tags: .net-core, servicestack

We have been using servicestack (5.8.0) on .net core for a while now, but we have recently started getting an which seems to be thrown within servicestack:

````
Could not Set-Cookie 'ss-id': IFeatureCollection has been disposed.
Object name: 'Collection'.```
````

and

```
System.ObjectDisposedException: IFeatureCollection has been disposed.
Object name: 'Collection'.
at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.Features.FeatureReferences`1.ThrowContextDisposed()
at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.DefaultHttpContext.get_RequestServices()
at ServiceStack.Host.NetCore.NetCoreRequest.TryResolveT in C:\BuildAgent\work\3481147c480f4a2f\src\ServiceStack\Host\NetCore\NetCoreRequest.cs:line 59
at ServiceStack.ServiceStackHost.GetCacheClient(IRequest req) in C:\BuildAgent\work\3481147c480f4a2f\src\ServiceStack\ServiceStackHost.Runtime.cs:line 729
at ServiceStack.ServiceExtensions.RemoveSession(IRequest httpReq, String sessionId) in C:\BuildAgent\work\3481147c480f4a2f\src\ServiceStack\ServiceExtensions.cs:line 100
at ServiceStack.Auth.AuthProvider.Logout(IServiceBase service, Authenticate request) in C:\BuildAgent\work\3481147c480f4a2f\src\ServiceStack\Auth\AuthProvider.cs:line 102
at ServiceStack.Auth.AuthenticateService.Authenticate(Authenticate request) in C:\BuildAgent\work\3481147c480f4a2f\src\ServiceStack\Auth\AuthenticateService.cs:line 348
at ELetting.WebService.AppHost.<>c__DisplayClass1_0.<Configure>b__5(IRequest httpReq, IResponse httpRes, Object requestDto) in C:\TeamCity\InteraciveBuildAgentKAH\work\1eb375e8315a0940\ELettingWebService\Startup.cs:line 177
at ServiceStack.ServiceStackHost.ApplyRequestFiltersSingleAsync(IRequest req, IResponse res, Object requestDto) in C:\BuildAgent\work\3481147c480f4a2f\src\ServiceStack\ServiceStackHost.Runtime.cs:line 180
at ServiceStack.ServiceStackHost.ApplyRequestFiltersAsync(IRequest req, IResponse res, Object requestDto) in C:\BuildAgent\work\3481147c480f4a2f\src\ServiceStack\ServiceStackHost.Runtime.cs:line 132
at ServiceStack.Host.RestHandler.ProcessRequestAsync(IRequest req, IResponse httpRes, String operationName) in C:\BuildAgent\work\3481147c480f4a2f\src\ServiceStack\Host\RestHandler.cs:line 122
```

Unfortunately, the error seems to be sporadic and intermittent - so have struggled to get an exact repro.  I know from other posts that this is to do with accessing the underlying IHttpContextAccessor  - but given we never access this directly, we are struggling to get to the bottom of this one.  The top error shows its within the code that handles the authentication cookies, but that again is not in our control?

Does anybody else happen to have seen this?

Thanks
David

Comment: From Googling [this Exception is common](https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/issues/20840) if the Request Context either doesn't exist or has been terminated early. Are you using `IHttpContextAccessor`? Also make sure you're not using `async void` anywhere in your App which isn't supported in ASP.NET Core.

Comment: We never use IHttpContextAccessor directly, only service stack is using internally.  We don't use async void anywhere.  So at a loss

Comment: Yeah same. Are these logout requests called from a Web App (e.g. HTML or Ajax) or from an API? Perhaps the client terminated the connection immediately after issuing their logout request, e.g. like it was sent from a `windows.onunload` event.

Comment: I think I have found the culprit - we have a service which will try to log in the user that has just been registered by executing "ResolveService<AuthenticateService>().Post(new Authenticate { provider = CredentialsAuthProvider.Name, UserName = req.Email, Password = req.Password })".  The request is an advanced registration form which takes a lot of extra data.  Not doing this causes the error not to occur, but will then force the user to log in after registering.  Is there a better supported way to achieve logging the user straight in?

Comment: The API Request that's failing is a `Authenticate{provider="logout"}` request which is being sent after the Request has terminated. In your AuthProvider you can override `Logout()`  and wrap `base.Logout(...)` in a try catch to inspect what request is causing it to fail and hopefully where in the Request Pipeline it's being terminated.